# assetic:dump --watch ignore changes on windows

Tags: symfony, assetic

I would like to ask you about this problem. I'm using symfony 2.3 and I have problem witch assetic.

If I run assetic:dump, everything works fine. But if I use --watch to rebuild after every change, it doesn't work. It does nothing. I'm working on windows.

Has someone experiences with this problem? Really thanks.

Comment: Did you open the console as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to write below to console?

```
php app/console assetic:dump --force --watch
```